# Image file not getting added to indexddb - intermittent issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

We are using indexeddb to implement background sync with service worker.

It is working fine on all systems, however, intermittently it fails to add images into the indexeddb, getting no error messages only a warning that "data may be stale". Below is the code sample.

Issue got replicated on mobile Chrome browser version 66

```js
function storetoIndexeddb(id, file) {
        var docID = ''


        docID = $scope[id]
        var file = file;
        var file64 = null;

        // IndexedDB
        var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.OIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB,
            IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.OIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction,
            dbVersion = 1;
        var dbName = "testDb",
            db;

        if (!indexedDB) {
            alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Such and such feature will not be available.");
        }

        // Create/open database
        var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);

        request.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("Error creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
        };

        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
            console.log("Success creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
            db = event.target.result;
            db.onerror = function(event) {
                console.log("Error creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
            };
            // Interim solution for Google Chrome to create an objectStore. Will be deprecated
            if (db.setVersion) {
                if (db.version != dbVersion) {
                    var setVersion = db.setVersion(dbVersion);
                    setVersion.onsuccess = function() {
                        createObjectStore(db);
                        putScreenshotInDb();
                    };
                } else {
                    putScreenshotInDb();
                }
            } else {
                putScreenshotInDb();
            }
        };

        request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
            createObjectStore(event.target.result);
        };

        function createObjectStore(dataBase) {
            dataBase.createObjectStore("saveData");
        }

        function putScreenshotInDb() {

            var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);

            request.onerror = function(event) {
                console.log("Error creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
            };

            request.onsuccess = function(event) {
                console.log("Success creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
                db = event.target.result;
                db.onerror = function(event) {
                    console.log("Error creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
                };
                // Interim solution for Google Chrome to create an objectStore. Will be deprecated
                transaction = db.transaction(["saveData"], "readwrite");

                transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
                    console.log('complete', event)
                };
                transaction.onerror = function(event) {
                    console.log('erooor', event)
                };
                var putreq = transaction.objectStore("saveData")
                putreq.put(file, $routeParams.serviceRequestId + 'XXX' + $scope.inspectData.assetId + "XXX" + docID + 'XXXinspImage');

                $scope.imageStorageRef[id].uploaded = true;
                $scope.loading = false;

            };



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a probable reason for this behavior of indexeddb and could also replicate the same issue on a physical device.

Indexed DB stores data on the physical memory and as the page [Indexed DB best practices](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/indexeddb-best-practices#writing_to_storage_may_fail), suggests, in case the device is running low on storage, Android may not allocate memory to the browser and hence to the db. In the above scenario, indexeddb's `put` operation comes in the success callback and doesn't thow any error nor the file is added to the memory. 
Have to implement a get operation in an independent transaction to confirm
the success of `put`.